# Javascript Live Nodelist Loop

Tags: javascript, nodelist

Maybe someone else asked the same questions , but i didnt find any similar results in questions that may already have your answer so i will go ahead ask my question.I  know that is alive list and when the first className change the list is going from 3 items to 2 . So the i now is 1 so thats why it skipped the "second item" from the list. Whats the best way to include all the items in a live Node List in loops ?  (Maybe use a static one?)

```js
        var hotElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hot");
        var i;
        var len = hotElements.length;

        for ( i= 0; i < len ;  i++) {
            hotElements[i].className = "pink";
  }
```

```css
        .hot {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  weight: 700;
}
.cool {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 35px;
```

```html
    <h1 id="header"> List King </h1>
<h2> Buy grocceries </h2>
<ul>
  <li id="one" class="hot"> Fresh </li>
  <li id="two" class="hot"> Fresh 1</li>
  <li id="three" class="hot"> Fresh 2 </li>
   <li id="one" class="cool"> Fresh </li>
  <li id="two" class="cool"> Fresh 1</li>
  <li id="three" class="cool"> Fresh 2 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Just change the class of the first element in the list: `hotElements[0].className = "pink";` while iterating. Or iterate backwards, or use `querySelectorAll` to get a static list.

Comment: @Teemu You can then also remove the `len` and `i` variable and use `hotElements[0]` as the loop condition and use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: @Xufox Jup, that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach that was used in the past is to loop over the collection backwards, that way if an item is removed it doesn't affect the position of any of the remaining elements:

```
var hotElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hot"),
  i;

for (i = hotElements.length - 1; 0 <= i;  i--) {
  hotElements[i].className = "pink";
}
```

One advantage to this approach over the `while(hotElements.length > 0)` solution that [NikxDa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4459695/nikxda) proposed is that it doesn't rely on elements getting removed if you were conditionally applying the new `className` instead of doing to every element.

You could also convert the live node collection to a real array that will not change.

Using ES2015 it is quite easy to do using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) syntax:

```
var hotElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hot");

[...hotElements].forEach(function (element) {
  element.className = "pink";
});
```

You can also do it in ES5 with a little more code:

```
var hotElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hot");

Array.prototype.slice.call(hotElements).forEach(function (element) {
  element.className = "pink";
});
```

Using `slice` to convert to an array won't work in IE < 9... but at this point in time that probably isn't a concern.

One more approach would be to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). It returns a non-live NodeList, so if you used it to find the elements you could still loop over it forwards:

```
var hotElements = document.querySelectorAll(".hot"),
  i,
  len = hotElements.length;

for (i = 0; i < len ;  i++) {
    hotElements[i].className = "pink";
}
```

Interesting related article: [A comprehensive dive into NodeLists, Arrays, converting NodeLists and understanding the DOM](https://toddmotto.com/a-comprehensive-dive-into-nodelists-arrays-converting-nodelists-and-understanding-the-dom/)

Comment: Great answer the is only one small mistake on the first method . On the for loop we should do hotItems.length -1;

Comment: @UselessCode Thanks! I do not know this method. This is funny usage

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` is live, that means that elements will automatically be removed when their className changes.

Try this:

```js
var hotElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hot");

// While loop to iterate while there are items left
while(hotElements.length > 0) {
    hotElements[0].className = "pink";  
}
```

```css
.hot {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  weight: 700;
}
.cool {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 35px;
```

```html
<h1 id="header"> List King </h1>
<h2>Buy groceries</h2>
<ul>
  <li id="one" class="hot"> Fresh </li>
  <li id="two" class="hot"> Fresh 1</li>
  <li id="three" class="hot"> Fresh 2 </li>
  <li id="one" class="cool"> Fresh </li>
  <li id="two" class="cool"> Fresh 1</li>
  <li id="three" class="cool"> Fresh 2 </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So title Javascript Live Nodelist Loop.
and no one bothers that the:

```
var hotElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hot")
console.log(hotElements)//it's a HTML collection not Nodlist
```

I am just beginner, but this I know...